# ggplotGrob function is not found when I use it in a package which imports ggplot2

Tags: r, import, ggplot2, namespaces, dependencies

I have a package located here on
[Github](https://github.com/Ward9250/HybRIDS) which makes use of ggplot2 and so I import it in my NAMESPACE file and my DESCRIPTION FILE

NAMESPACE:

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0): do not edit by hand

export(HybRIDS)
exportClasses(HybRIDS)
import(Biostrings)
import(ape)
import(ggplot2)
import(grid)
import(gridExtra)
importFrom(png,readPNG)
useDynLib(HybRIDS)
```

DESCRIPTION:

```
Package: HybRIDS
Type: Package
Title: Detection and dating of Recombinant Regions in DNA sequence data.
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-12-18
Author: Ben J. Ward
Maintainer: Ben J. Ward <b.ward@uea.ac.uk>
Description: An R package for the detection and dating of
    Recombinant Regions in DNA sequence data.
License: GPL-2
Depends: methods
Imports: 
    Rcpp (>= 0.11.0),ggplot2,grid,gridExtra,png,ape,Biostrings
LinkingTo: Rcpp
Suggests: knitr,testthat
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

However when I use some of the plotting functionality in the package I get an error:

```
Error: could not find function "ggplotGrob"
```

And my trace-back in RStudio takes me to these few lines in my package:

```
arrangeGrob(bars, legendgrob, widths = c(1, 0.13), ncol = 2) at TripletReference.R#244
6 plotBars(plottingSettings) at TripletReference.R#157
5 x$plotTriplet(plotSettings) at TripletReference.R#361
4 FUN(X[[1L]], ...) 
3 lapply(tripletsToPlot, function(x) x$plotTriplet(plotSettings)) at TripletReference.R#361
2 triplets$plotTriplets(Selections, plottingSettings) at HybRIDSObject.R#253
1 test$plotTriplets()
```

That line that uses arrangeGrob at TripletReference.R#244 is quite simple. It takes two inputs, one is a ggplot object generated earlier in the function by the following:

```
bars <- ggplot(plottingFrame, aes(x = X, y = as.factor(Y))) +
                               geom_raster(aes(fill = colour)) + scale_fill_identity() +
                               xlab("Approximate Base Position") +
                               ylab("Sequence Name") +
                               scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(from = 1, to = plottingSettings$MosaicScale, by = plottingSettings$MosaicScale / 10), plottingSettings$MosaicScale), labels = c(frame$bpX[seq(from = 1, to = plottingSettings$MosaicScale, by = plottingSettings$MosaicScale / 10)], max(frame$bpX))) + 
                               scale_y_discrete(labels = c(ContigNames[3], ContigNames[2], ContigNames[1]))
```

It's lengthy but there's nothing special about it - it's a fairly normal use of ggplot and some geoms and scales.

The second input is a rasterGrob created from an image:

```
legendgrob <- rasterGrob(image=legend)
```

All the arrangeGrob line is supposed to do is take the two things and arrange them in one grob, side by side - a grob with two columns.

Notice I haven't in any of the above, tried to use the function that is not found myself (the ggplotGrob function).

I have checked R's documentation of ggplotGrob with `?ggplotGrob`, and whilst my package is loaded, if I do ggplot2::ggplotGrob, the following is returned:

```
function (x) 
{
    ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x))
}
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

So I know the ggplot2 namespace has been loaded - my question is why is my package throwing this error, even when I have imported ggplot2? and the only Depends ggplot2 has now are stats and methods?

Thanks,
Ben W.

Comment: I think I've found the answer - is this because gridExtra does not import ggplot2 so the arrangeGrob of gridExtra is not finding ggplotGrob of ggplot2?

Comment: One potential problem I see is that `gridExtra` depends on `grid`, so when you import `gridExtra`, its' `grid`-based functionality will break. You'll have to put `gridExtra` to `DEPENDS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `ggplot2` under depends, rather than imports, in your DESCRIPTION file.

I've had a similar issue while using the `grid.arrange` function from `gridExtra`, and this solution worked for me.

My, admittedly rudimentary, understanding of the issue is that `gridExtra` is calling the  `ggplotGrob` function at a point when the `ggplot2` library isn't yet loaded.

Comment: This is what I deduced too - or at least something similar, gridExtra uses stuff from ggplot2 but ggplot2 is only a suggests. Therefore, and so searches for the ggplot2 function it's trying to call through the search path - so attached packages, and not through its imports.